# Cannot access the Windows shared folder on MacBook

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, macos, macbook

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGOU2EgtNyQ) to access a shared folder of windows on MacBook. I have done the following steps:

1. Created a `shared` folder in Windows.
2. Given it the permissions that everyone on the network can read/write it.
3. Got my Wireless LAN IP address from `cmd.exe` by running `ipconfig`
4. Set the sharing settings in MacBook.
5. `Go`->`Connect to server`->`smb://192.x.x.x`
6. Entered the username and password for my window's user account (admin).

**PROBLEM:** After the 6th step the login windows shakes to show that the username/password is not accepted.

**PS:** In the finder window, my MacBook shows the **ADMIN-PC** under the category of Network. It means that the MacBook is detecting my Windows PC but not letting me login into shared folder.

Comment: see if this might be similar - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152900/share-mac-files-yosemite-with-windows/152906#152906 [even if it is the other way round]

Comment: In my case, I am able to access the shared folder of Macbook on my windows computer but the other way round is not working

Comment: I've had this happen... I'm just trying to remember the 'fix'...

Comment: Could firewall be a problem? and how do I fix it?

Comment: No, if it were a firewall issue it wouldn't connect - you're connecting but being actively rejected [somewhere]

Comment: When it asks, try using the `<WindowsComputerName>\<WindowsUserName>` pattern for the user name. (ie: `Admin-PC\SKM`)

Comment: no, didn't work